# Young adult book where a girl fights in a fantasy world but turns out she was just in a coma from a car accident. Read it in the 1990s

Tags: story-identification

I was in middle school when I read this. Not sure if it’s older than the 90s.  Girl was fighting, maybe becoming royalty in the fantasy world and she then starts complaining of a headache.  Turn out she’s dreamed the fantasy world and the fighting was her trying to stay alive in a coma from a car crash over a bridge.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Is it the same as [this book](https://www.reddit.com/r/whatsthatbook/comments/17oqog0/yachildrens_fantasymain_character_katherine_is_in/)? Is the girl's name _Katherine_ and does it end with her waking in hospital with a mysterious dwarf present?

Comment: I don’t believe it’s that book, there wasn’t a dwarf when she woke up.  The story ended with the fantasy world definitely have been a dream during her time trying to survive in a coma. Thanks for the suggestion though, I got really excited as I loved reading this book in the 90s.